# count frequency of items in one column in relation to criteria in another column in python

Tags: python

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

| Category | Topic |
| --- | --- |
| Category1 | Topic1 |
| Category2 | Topic2 |
| Category1 | Topic2 |
| Category3 | Topic3 |
| Category2 | Topic3 |
| Category3 | Topic3 |

And I want an output like this:

| Category | Topic | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Category1 | Topic1 |  |
|  | Topic2 |  |
|  | Topic3 |  |
| Catgeory2 | Topic1 |  |
|  | Topic2 |  |
|  | Topic3 |  |
| Category3 | Topic1 |  |
|  | Topic2 |  |
|  | Topic3 |  |

I am just starting out with python and I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: you can check out `groupby` but I'm guessing you may actually be looking for a pivot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: What should go in the `frequency` column? The relative frequency of `topic1`, `topic2` etc. within a `category`? (e.g. the sum for the first three rows of your output example would be 1?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look at the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a quality question. In particular, it's good to give a sense of what you already tried including things that you searched for on SO.

Answer (score 1):

If the `frequency` is meant to capture the frequency of topic *within* each category, then, a basic approch involves:

```py
df.groupby('Category')['Topic'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Which is a `Series`. For example, on your input data, we get:

```
Category   Topic 
Category1  Topic1    0.5
           Topic2    0.5
Category2  Topic2    0.5
           Topic3    0.5
Category3  Topic3    1.0
Name: Topic, dtype: float64
```

For an output organized as per your example, that appears to be a `DataFrame` with three columns:

```py
out = (
    df
    .groupby('Category')['Topic']
    .value_counts(normalize=True)
    .to_frame('frequency')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Again, on your input sample:

```py
>>> out
    Category   Topic  frequency
0  Category1  Topic1        0.5
1  Category1  Topic2        0.5
2  Category2  Topic2        0.5
3  Category2  Topic3        0.5
4  Category3  Topic3        1.0
```